# Finding the number of clusters in a circular array

Tags: java

Defining a cluster as 2 or more elements in an array that applies circularly, I'm trying to get 3 things out of an array:

The largest cluster size, the number of clusters in the array, and the average cluster size. An example would look like:

> 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1

There would be two clusters here, the largest cluster would be 5 elements, the average size would be 3.5 (or 3)

and here's what I have

```
private static boolean isCluster(int i) {
        if (table[i] == 1 && table[i + 1] == 1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void setClusters() {
        ArrayList<Integer> clusterSizes = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean continuousCluster = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < table.length - 1; i++) {
            if (isCluster(i)) {
                clusterSize++;
                continuousCluster = true;
            } else if (continuousCluster && table[i + 1] == 0) { // cluster is broken
                numberofClusters++;
                clusterSize++;
                if (clusterSize > largestCluster) largestCluster = clusterSize;
                clusterSizes.add(clusterSize);
                clusterSize = 0;
                continuousCluster = false;
            }
            if(isCluster(table.length-2)){
                numberofClusters++;
            }
        }
        if (table[0] == 1 && table[table.length - 1] == 1) {
            numberofClusters--;
            clusterSizes.set(0, (clusterSizes.get(0) + clusterSizes.get(clusterSizes.size() - 1)));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < clusterSizes.size(); i++) {
            averageClusterSize += clusterSizes.get(i);
        }
        if(numberofClusters != 0) {
            averageClusterSize /= numberofClusters;
        }
        else{
            averageClusterSize = 0;
        }
    }
```

What I have works fine up until it should add the values if the clusters are circular.

Comment: if there are no zeroes, you have a single cluster of size arraysize. If you have a zero, rotate all data so there's a zero at the end( or start). Now you don't need an algorithm for a circular list.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine if there is a so-called *circular* cluster like this:

```
if (table[0] == 1 && table[table.length - 1] == 1) {
    //there is a circular cluster
    //do your calcs (count the ones from the beggining and from the end, etc...
}
```

I think you are able to do the rest of logic...